# isnull().sum() returning incorrect figure

Tags: random-forest, data-science-model, dataframe

I am doing a prediction using RandomForestRegressor.

Below is the code for test data:

```py
    X = test_set.drop(['C_Nxt10DMx'], axis=1) # drop labels for training set
    Y = test_set['C_Nxt10DMx'].copy()                 
    test_prepared     = full_pipeline.transform(X)
    final_predictions = forest_reg.predict(test_prepared)
    final_mse = mean_squared_error(Y, final_predictions)
    final_rmse = np.sqrt(final_mse)
    (forest_rmse*100)/Y.mean()
```

I am printing `Y.isnull().sum()` and it is returning a 0 value. However, when I trying to bind the value in a data frame, it is returning an incorrect figure.

```py
df =  pd.DataFrame() 
df['pred'] = final_predictions
df['Label'] = Y
print(Y.isnull().sum())
print(df['Label'].isnull().sum())

# 7646
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly it's an index issue?  What is `Y.index`?

Comment: `df` and `Y` have different indices (they don't match). That's why you have missing values in `df['label']`.